# Google Gson treats every JSON local file as a string even when its not

Tags: java, json, io, gson, json-deserialization

I am constantly getting `Expected BEGIN_TYPE but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $` error. I've read about that error, but I am experiencing something different.

When I try to use `gson.fromJson()` on a `JSON` string I've created in my app it compiles fine.

```
     ArrayList<MyCar> cars = new ArrayList<>();
     cars.add(new MyCar());
     cars.add(new MyCar());
     String json = gson.toJson(cars);
```

This compiles.

```
     Type carList = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyCar>>(){}.getType();
     ArrayList<MyCar> myCars = gson.fromJson(json, carList);
```

This compiles as well.

My problem is when I try to read from a local file I've either written myself or downloaded from the web (I have run all local files on `JsonLint` and they're valid).

Here is the JSON when written to a file named `testingArray.json`:

```
[{
    "model": "I3",
    "manufacturer": "Audi",
    "features": ["wifi", "bluetooth", "charging"]
}, {
    "model": "I3",
    "manufacturer": "Audi",
    "features": ["wifi", "bluetooth", "charging"]
}, {
    "model": "I3",
    "manufacturer": "Audi",
    "features": ["wifi", "bluetooth", "charging"]
}]
```

It clearly begins with brackets and not quotes.

But this:

```
 Type carList = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyCar>>(){}.getType();
 ArrayList<MyCar> myCars = gson.fromJson(basePath + "testingArray.json", carList);
```

Doesn't compile and gives the aforementioned error.

I am dumbfounded as to why, because when I run `fromJson` on a `POJO` like `JSON` it works. But if I run the SAME JSON data from a local file it doesn't work. It always reads it as a string even if it begins with brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path to the file is treated literally as `JSON` payload, so this why you see this exception. You need to create `Reader` based on path to the file:

```
try (FileReader jsonReader = new FileReader(basePath + "testingArray.json")) {
    Type carList = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyCar>>(){}.getType();
    List<MyCar> myCars = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, carList); 
}
```

Comment: It works! And, any reason why GSON requires you to wrap the path in FileReader while Jackson doesn't?

Comment: @Fletcher, this is because of [method overloading](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/). When you provide `String` variable `Gson` treats it as raw `JSON`. In case you want to provide `JSON` from file or other source you need to use `Reader` to make it clear that `stream` should be used.